# Each function is not working inside ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, each

I have a table in which I am inserting customer code and customer name. If record is already available in table then It should through alert. I tried but which I used each function inside $.Ajax() success then It stops working. If each function commented then it works fine.
Below is My code.

```js
 $("#cust_name").keypress(function(e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("ReturnCustName")',
                    data: { custCode: $(this).val() },
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (typeof (data.cust_name) === "undefined") {
                            alert('Customer code is not available !');
                            $("#cust_name").val('');
                        } else {

                            var IsLoggedIn1 = "False";
                            $("table#divPOList > tbody  > tr").each(function (i, row) {
                                var code = $(":nth-child(1)", row).html();
                                if (code == cust_code) {
                                    alert("Record alredy exist");
                                    IsLoggedIn1 = "true";
                                }

                            });

                            if (IsLoggedIn1 == "False") {
                               
                                $('#divPOList').append('<tr><td>' +
                                    data.cust_code +
                                    '</td><td>' +
                                    data.cust_name +
                                    '</td></tr>');
                                $("#cust_name").val('');
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Your help may appreciated.

Thanks
Nandkumar Satpute

Comment: It does not appear that `cust_code` is defined anywhere that I can see. Did you mean `if (code == data.cust_code)`?

Comment: Yes I was missing 'data.' thanks, it is working now

Comment: Also if you want to check that table tbody is not empty then you have to apply a little bit different code